# Colab pro gpu doesn't work on local vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-colaboratory

I tried to use `Colab Pro's GPU` on my local `vscode` via `colab-ssh` by using `ngrok`.
But as you can see below, when I check `nvidia-smi` on my local vscode terminal, it didn't show Memory-Usage.
What should I do?

```
Sat Jul 16 04:08:30 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.48.07    Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   35C    P0    29W / 250W | Function Not Found   |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```